# Please I'm stuck in this homogeneous equation

Tags: integration

$$(xy'-y)\arctan y/x=x;(xy'-y)=x/(\arctan y/x)$$

$$y=ux$$
$$y’=u’x+u$$
$$(x(u’x+u)-ux)$$
$$\arctan(xu)/x =x; x^2 u'\arctan u=x; x^2$$
$$du/dx= x/(\arctan (u))$$
$$du/dx=1/(x\arctan (u))$$
$$dx/x=\arctan(u)du$$
$$∫dx/x=\ln(x)$$

.... Help?

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to solve:

$\displaystyle \left(x  \frac{dy}{dx} -y\right) tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} = x$

Letting $y = x v$, yields $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}  =  v+x \frac{dv}{dx}$, so:

$\displaystyle \left(x \left(v + x \frac{dv}{dx}\right)-x v\right) \tan^{-1}v = x$

Simplifying yields:

$\displaystyle x^2 \frac{dv}{dx} \tan^{-1}v = x$

Divide both sides by $x^2$, yielding:

$\displaystyle \frac{dv}{dx} \tan^{-1}v  =  \frac{1}{x}$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$, yielding:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dv}{dx} \tan^{-1}v dx  =   \int \frac{1}{x} dx$, so

$\displaystyle v \tan^{-1}v -\frac{1}{2} \ln(v^2+1)  =  c_1+\ln(x)$, where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant.

Substituting back for $y  =  x v$, yields:

$$\displaystyle \frac{y \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})}{x}  -\frac{1}{2} \ln\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}+1\right) = c_1+\ln(x)$$

Comment: Nice work! $\;\;+\;\;$